# linq ToArray() changes array length

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following:

```
Dictionary<int,int> dict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
dict.Add(1, 3);
dict.Add(3, 4);

int [] a = new int [] { 1, 2, 3 };
int [] b = new int [a.Length];

Console.WriteLine("a:");
a.Dump(); //using linqpad here

Console.WriteLine("b:");
b.Dump(); //using linqpad here

b = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("b after linq:");
b.Dump(); //using linqpad here
```

**RESULTS**

```
a: 1 2 3

b: 0 0 0

b after linq: 3 1
```

I have an existing array `a`. I create an new array of the same length `b`. After linq query with `ToArray()` values are added to new array `b`, but the length changes. Is there a way to retain the original array length while still adding the values to it?

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
b after linq: 3 1 0
```

Comment: You're **REASSIGNING** your b array with the value of the keys from `Dictionary<>` so the result is correct in any way.

Comment: You have to assign the result of `dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();` to another variable and then do `Array.Copy` to `b` from there.

Comment: The ToArray() method does not change the length of b. It creates a new array from the two dictionary keys. The 'b =' assignment replaces the old b array with the newly created array. You might want to loop the new array and assign each value to the corresponding index in array b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already posted by Sergey, you are reassigning the content of `b` with your Linq statement. If you want to fill the rest of the array with zeroes up to a given number use this after the Linq statement:

```
Array.Resize(ref b, a.Length);
```

This way you get your desired result `3 1 0`

Note that this operation creates a new array and replaces the existing variable `b` with this array.

Answer (score 2):

This is an assignment operation:

```
b = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

it replaces reference to array `new int [a.Length]` which you have in variable `b` with new reference to array created by LINQ query. Assignment will not change values in the first array.

If you want to 'merge' two arrays by replacing corresponding items from first array with items from the second array, you can create custom extension method (there is no default LINQ extension for that):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWith<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> replacement)
{
    using (var sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var replacementIterator = replacement.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            yield return replacementIterator.MoveNext()
                ? replacementIterator.Current
                : sourceIterator.Current;

        // you can remove this loop if you want to preserve source length
        while (replacementIterator.MoveNext())
            yield return replacementIterator.Current;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
b = b.MergeWith(dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key)).ToArray();
```

Output:

```
b after linq: 3 1 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You only add "3" and "1" to your dictionary. 
If you want "3 1 0" as result you will need to add a "0" to the dictionary, too.